# Docusign email notification for embedded signing case

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the embedded signing api using JSON requests to create online signing sessions in the broswser. There is only one prospective configured in the template and the authencitcation method is email.

I do not want the email address that I am sending to receive an email notification. How do I turn this off. Ive looked at preferences--features to turn off email notification but cant find any setting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to the DocuSign web console as an Administrator in the sending DocuSign account, and navigate to **Preferences** >> **Features**. Enable (check) the **Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers** setting and Disable (uncheck) the **Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers**.   Click the SAVE button (all the way at the bottom of the page) to save the changes.

[image: Settings]

These settings make it so that DocuSign will not send any emails to Recipients that you create via the API and specify as embedded/captive (i.e., by setting **clientUserId** property to indicate that they will be accessing the Envelope via your application).

---

#### Update

If you are using the New DocuSign Experience then follow the instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-signing-settings)

See the Document delivery section.

Comment: Edited my initial response to indicate that the second setting (Use Envelope Complete Email...) should be DISabled.

Comment: Thanks Kim, was aware of just the first one.