# Docusign Void Envelope Notification

Tags: docusignapi

When I void an envelope through rest api, Docusign notifies the customer for the void. Is there anyway to change this?

Thanks.

Comment: If this transaction is "remote signing" (i.e: DocuSign sends out the email asking the recipient to sign/etc), then no.

Comment: FYI: With regards to remote signing, if the recipient has an actual DocuSign account, they can specify their OWN email preferences for notifications (Preferences -> Member Profile -> Manage email Notifications).  The sender cannot dictate which emails the recipient would receive for remote signing flows.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but these are customers that just sign a form, they don't register accounts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the signer, then void the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the recipient from a remote signer to an embedded signer by adding a clientid and then void the envelope. Embedded signers repress all e-mail notifications by default. The following specifies how to create an embedded signer: [Link](https://demo.docusign.net/Member/MemberAccountEditor.aspx?Action=Edit&ct=Features)
This other post  describes how to make sure embedded signing notifications are disabled: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995662/docusign-email-notification-for-embedded-signing-case)

Comment: This seems like a good solution. When I change to embedded signer, will the client get a notificaiton? Also, how do I update an envelope to use embedded signing? I know how to create one, but I'm not sure how to switch to embedded signing