# Docusign Email Contract after Embedded Signing

Tags: node.js, email, docusignapi

I was my understanding that unless turned off Docusign automatically sent an email to the people who signed the contract when it was completed

Currently when signing an embedded contract no email is being sent out.

We have followed the instructions here

[Docusign email notification for embedded signing case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995662/docusign-email-notification-for-embedded-signing-case)

and turned on emails for embedded signings.

We have checked spam folders to make sure it is not getting marked as spam

The contract signing is completed, however, no email is being sent

Below is an example of one of the requests sent to Docusign. Everything works perfectly. We sign this document at

/sign/first/175687

Then we are redirected to

/sign/second/175687/{envelopeid}?event=signing_complete

where the cosigner (if they exist) signs

Then we redirect back to another page to finish the process.

```
  {
 method: 'POST',

uri: 'https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxxxxx/envelopes',

body: '{
"emailSubject": "Agreement",
"templateId": "xxxxxxxx",
"templateRoles": [{
  "email": "myemailn@gmail.com",
  "name": "Developer TestingCO",
  "roleName": "signer",
  "clientUserId": "1001",
  "tabs": {
    "initialHereTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/12/"
    }],
    "signHereTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/FirstSigner/"
    }],
    "dateSignedTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/SignDate/",
      "font": "Arial",
      "fontSize": "Size10",
      "anchorYOffset": -10
    }],
    "textTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/Contract/",
      "anchorYOffset": -5,
      "anchorXOffset": "-8",
      "font": "Arial",
      "bold": true,
      "fontSize": "Size10",
      "value": "175687"
    }, {
      "anchorString": "/Fname/",
      "anchorYOffset": -5,
      "anchorXOffset": "-8",
      "font": "Arial",
      "bold": true,
      "fontSize": "Size10",
      "value": "Developer TestingCO"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
  "name": "Developer Testing",
  "roleName": "cosigner",
  "clientUserId": "1002",
  "tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/CoSigner/"
    }],
    "dateSignedTabs": [{
      "anchorString": "/coDate/",
      "font": "Arial",
      "fontSize": "Size10",
      "anchorYOffset": -10
    }]
  }
}],
"status": "sent"
}',

headers: {
  'X-DocuSign-Authentication': '{
  "Username": "xxx",
  "Password": "xxx",
  "IntegratorKey": "xxx"
}
' 
  }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you are in production already since you are hitting `na2.docusign.net/...`, are you positive you have enabled/disabled the two account options related to embedded emails on the right account and not your demo sandbox account?

Comment: Yes, This is the final stage of testing so we moved to the live server to make sure everything was set up correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure you have the following configuration for the DS account:

- Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers = unchecked
- Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers = checked

Also sanity check that the envelope you are creating using the API is being created from the account with these settings.

Comment: I was missing the Use Envelope Complete Email field. Thank you for your help!