# DosuSign Embedded Signing: Prevent DocuSing from sending email

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to do Embedded Signing and I want to send the email to the Signers myself instead of having DocuSign send it.

I've found this post:
[Docusign email notification for embedded signing case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995662/docusign-email-notification-for-embedded-signing-case)

That describes two parameters. I have not been able to find the second one (*Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers*) in my testing account.

Is this option no longer available? Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For embedded signers DocuSign will never send an email letting the signer know they have a document **awaiting** signature. The two emails that are sent can either be Signature Notification and/or Completion email. Signature Notification is sent to the signer immediately after signing, while Completion emails are sent all at once only at the end when the last signer completes the envelope.

The options are both still available in the classic UI under Preferences --> Features. [image]

### Update

If you are using the New DocuSign Experience then follow the instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-signing-settings)

See the Document delivery section.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware there was a "Classic" UI. Why would DocuSign create a "new" UI that would let you do less things is beyond me.

Comment: The "New DocuSign Experience" is going to be the core product eventually. It was initially just released to Singe User web customers but will become the staple as parity to the classic UI is met. It doesn't quite get down the specific features, but you can find the parity list here: https://55f6937962225f1128cc-127e3962bd066ad8a614167b85206e23.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/New%20DS%20Experience%20Feature%20Availability%20Matrix.pdf

Comment: The "New DocuSign Experience"  also has the ability to update "Document Delivery" settings.